# Decoding the .xml file for values

Tags: shell, xml-parsing, compare, string-comparison

I want to get only values in from below lines

for example:

```
<property><name>yarn.authorization-provider</name><value>org.apache.ranger.authorization.yarn.authorizer.RangerYarnAuthorizer</value><source>programatically</source><source>job.xml</source></property>
<property><name>yarn.sharedcache.webapp.address</name><value>0.0.0.0:8788</value><source>yarn-default.xml</source><source>job.xml</source></property>
<property><name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name><value>3072</value><source>programatically</source><source>job.xml</source></property>
<property><name>mapreduce.framework.name</name><value>yarn</value><source>programatically</source><source>job.xml</source></property>
<property><name>mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps</name><value>0.80</value><source>programatically</source><source>job.xml</source></property>
<property><name>yarn.resourcemanager.client.thread-count</name><value>50</value><source>yarn-default.xml</source><source>job.xml</source></property>
```

I want to get property, value, source and source from above file.

yarn.authorization-provider | org.apache.ranger.authorization.yarn.authorizer.RangerYarnAuthorizer | programatically | job.xml --> from the first line

yarn.sharedcache.webapp.address | 0.0.0.0:8788 | yarn-default.xml | job.xml --> from line two

I have 900 lines .xml file from which I am trying to get the values. I tries in shell but it did not worked properly and I am not sure how to do it in python or any other language.

My final goal is to compare two of these kind of xml files which might or might not have same properties.

Comment: ...so your intent is pipe-separated output?

Comment: Are there any `xmlns=` declarations in your document you aren't showing in the example snippets?

Answer (score 2):

Using XMLStarlet to convert your input file to a pipe-delimited format, as shown in your question as intended output form:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//property' \
  -v './name'      -o ' | ' \
  -v './value'     -o ' | ' \
  -v './source[1]' -o ' | ' \
  -v './source[2]' -n \
  <in.xml >out.txt
```

To break this down:

- `-m '//property'` matches `property` elements anywhere in the document.
- `-v './name'` prints the value of any `name` element found immediately under that property.
- `-o ' | '` emits as output the literal string `|`
- `-v './value' -o ' | '` does likewise for the value of any `value` element.
- `-v './source[1]'` and `-v './source[2]'` refer to the first and second `source` elements (note that XPath, the language used here, is 1-indexed rather than 0-indexed, so `1` is genuinely the first entry).
- `-n` prints a literal newline as output.

The only case where this is likely to fail (with input that is genuinely valid and well-formed XML) is if the input document actually contains a `xmlns=something` declaration higher in the hierarchy, in which case the *actual* elements aren't `name`, `value` and `source`, but `{something}name`, `{something}value` and `{something}source`; when asking questions about XML in the future, please be sure to include enough context to identify this scenario.

---

If you don't have XMLStarlet on the system where you're deploying this code, you can use the `-C` option to ask it to emit an XSL transform which will perform the same operation:

```
xmlstarlet sel -C \
  -t -m '//property' \
  -v './name'      -o ' | ' \
  -v './value'     -o ' | ' \
  -v './source[1]' -o ' | ' \
  -v './source[2]' -n \
  >transform.xslt
```

...which will emit something along the lines of:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//property">
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="./name"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="./value"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="./source[1]"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="./source[2]"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="value-of-template">
    <xsl:param name="select"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$select"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($select)[position()&gt;1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Even without having XMLStarlet installed, you can then use the XSLTProc tool to apply this template:

```
xsltproc transform.xslt in.xml >out.txt
```

---

Wrapping your input in bare `<root>` and `</root>` elements to assemble a well-formed XML document, and running the above code, the output is:

```
yarn.authorization-provider | org.apache.ranger.authorization.yarn.authorizer.RangerYarnAuthorizer | programatically | job.xml
yarn.sharedcache.webapp.address | 0.0.0.0:8788 | yarn-default.xml | job.xml
yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb | 3072 | programatically | job.xml
mapreduce.framework.name | yarn | programatically | job.xml
mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps | 0.80 | programatically | job.xml
yarn.resourcemanager.client.thread-count | 50 | yarn-default.xml | job.xml
```

---

Inasmuch as your goal is to compare the properties in two XML files, by the way, consider the following usage:

```
diff <(xsltproc transform.xslt in1.xml | LANG=C sort -s) \
     <(xsltproc transform.xslt in2.xml | LANG=C sort -s)
```

If you're wanting to find only properties that differ, only properties that are identical, etc (and to do so more efficiently), consider applying that same usage pattern to the `comm` tool, as described in [BashFAQ #36](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036).

Comment: I don't have xmlstarlet installed.  I will have to try it.  +1.

Comment: See edits -- you don't actually need it installed to use transforms it generates.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, one should use a tool, such as python, that understands XML.  Alternatively, for a quick-and-dirty solution for your particular file, try:

```
$ sed -E 's/^([<][^>]*[>])+//; s/([<][^>]*[>])+$//; s/([<][^>]*[>])+/|/g' file.xml
yarn.authorization-provider|org.apache.ranger.authorization.yarn.authorizer.RangerYarnAuthorizer|programatically|job.xml
yarn.sharedcache.webapp.address|0.0.0.0:8788|yarn-default.xml|job.xml
yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb|3072|programatically|job.xml
mapreduce.framework.name|yarn|programatically|job.xml
mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps|0.80|programatically|job.xml
yarn.resourcemanager.client.thread-count|50|yarn-default.xml|job.xml
```

#### How it works

- `s/^([<][^>]*[>])+//`

  This removes all tags from the beginning of each line.
- `s/([<][^>]*[>])+$//`

  This removes all tags from the end of each line
- `s/([<][^>]*[>])+/|/g`

  This replaces all remaining tags with vertical bars, `|`.

In general, XML files can have `>` in the middle of tags and can also put line breaks in strange places.  Consequently, for these and other reasons, this solution is not robust.